# Stacked bar chart .offset() values for d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, offset

Would anyone know where I might find a list of .offset() values for a stacked bar chart?

I have found these four on github but I'm sure I have seen more elsewhere, I just cant remember where.

```
silhouette - center the stream, as in ThemeRiver.
wiggle - minimize weighted change in slope.
expand - normalize layers to fill the range [0,1].
zero - use a zero baseline, i.e., the y-axis.
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I misunderstand the question, but per the API, the four choices are as you described.  You can also create your own offset function, see:

https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Stack-Layout#wiki-offset